# Build error when trying to override an initializer in Xcode 6.3 Beta 3

Tags: swift, xcode6.3

The following code shows build error in Xcode 6.3 **Beta 3**. The code works in Xcode 6.2 and Xcode 6.3 Beta 2.

```
class MyView: UIView {
  override init() {
    super.init()
    // Some init logic ...
  }

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
}
```

### Error message

> initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass

### Workaround?

There is a possible workaround of creating a protocol with init methods mentioned in [Beta 3 release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.3_beta_3/Xcode_6.3_beta_3_Release_Notes.pdf). I could not make it work both both `init` and `init(frame: CGRect)` initializers.

How can I fix those build errors?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A designated initializer of a subclass needs to call the designated initializer of Superclass. A convenience initializer can only call another convenience initializer or a designated initializer of that class.

init() is a convenience initializer for UIView, if you subclass UIView you should call its designated initializer which is init(frame: frame)

```
override init() {
super.init(frame: frame)
// Some init logic ...
}
```

EDIT: Apparently in Beta 3, UIView doesn't have convenience initializer called as init, so you need to remove the override keyword too, now this is a designated initializer so you need to call superclass's designated initializer

```
init() {
super.init(frame: frame)
// Some init logic ...
}
```

EDIT: Although this works but I think a better way to write this would be:

```
convenience init() {
self.init(frame:CGRectZero)
}
```

Source:[Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID216)

> Rule 1 A designated initializer must call a designated initializer
>   from its immediate superclass.
>
> Rule 2 A convenience initializer must call another initializer from
>   the same class.
>
> Rule 3 A convenience initializer must ultimately call a designated
>   initializer.

Answer (score 1):

swift3 working :
**@Andrea** comment

> try to change `super.init()` in `self.init()`

Answer (score 0):

An additional way of resolving is to provide a default argument for the frame parameter of the UIView

```
override init(frame: CGRect = CGRectZero) {
     super.init(frame: frame)
     // custom code
}
```