# Cannot build my iOS app after update

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I have just updated my Mac and Xcode.

Mac: 10.10.3 (14D131)

Xcode: 6.3 (6D570)

Yesterday, I have built my app, and tested it on simulator and real iPhone device.

However, after the updates, now I am not able to build with the following errors:

1- Cannot load module 'UIKit' as "UiKit"

I used to use this import statment: `import UiKit` I have never used `import UIKit` with uppercase **UI** instead of the **Ui**

I have done a "find and replace" operation to replace 39 occurrences. Then I got the following errors on built:

2- 'Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass'. I have removed

3- Now I got many errors requiring me to change `as` to `as!`

I am getting lots of errors!! I have checked out a commit known to be working, but no use!

Is it related to the update? Am I missing something with this update?
[image]
[Fullscreen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqIPj.png)

Edit 2: After converting to Latest Swift Syntax and Cleaning everything. I got the following errors (But it is strange if I solved one error the all list changes):

[image: New Errors]

Comment: Have you updated to the latest version of Swift? Edit > Convert > To Latest Swift Syntax...

Comment: ... and read the Xcode 6.3 Release Notes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change everything to Swift 1.2 because the latest XCODE version don't support swift 1.1
[Here is a great Link about Swift 1.2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/95181/whats-new-in-swift-1-2)

Comment: I would rather stay with the previous Xcode. Convert to Latest Swift Syntax did not help me a lot :(

Comment: so you have an empty constructor that's the problem..In your example Code

Comment: There was many issues with my code after the update. Most of them are changes from ! to ? or add/remove !

Comment: Yes that's the new Swift 1.2 Syntax so the compiler help you a lot ! So do you have any Issues left ?

Answer (score 4):

Try first to convert your project to "Lastest swift syntax", then clean your project (and eventually Derived data)

[image]

Comment: I have switched to latest swift syntax. Cleaned and removed derived data. But still I have same issues. Any way to revert xcode back? :(

Comment: Can you show us the new errors? Btw, it must be UIKit but not UiKit

Comment: It seem that there some classes that have not been converted correctly to Swift 1.2. You have to add your self some ! for 'as' keyword. For error which has white point inside red circle, just click to that icon then choose to apply auto-correct. For Set<NSObject> problem, if you want to get all items, convert to array. For initialize problem, take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29068534/build-error-when-trying-to-override-an-initializer-in-xcode-6-3-beta-3

Answer (score 0):

Try by cleaning the project and deleting the derived data.

Answer (score -1):

It was caused by simple typo.
It should be UIKit - not UiKit or UIkit or any other spelling.
I solved my code with this simple change.
Hope that help.