# Error after update to Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6.3.2

I updated shortly to Swift 1.2 which comes with Xcode 6.3.2 and wrote a few lines of code:

```
let originView:UIView!

  override init() {

      super.init()

  }

  init(sourceView:UIView, menuItems:Array<String>){

      super.init()

      originView = sourceView
  }
```

This code runs perfect till I updated the new version of Xcode (6.3.2).

Now I get the following error: `Property 'self.originView' not initialized at super.init call`

Until now I can't find a solution for this because I'm still learning Swift.

Do someone of you know how I can solve this problem?

P.S It's not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29068534/build-error-when-trying-to-override-an-initializer-in-xcode-6-3-beta-3) because of this piece of code: `init(sourceView:UIView, menuItems:Array<String>)` instead of `override init(frame: CGRect)`.

**UPDATE:**

**New code:**

```
override convenience init() {

    self.init()
}

init(sourceView:UIView, menuItems:Array<String>){

    originView = sourceView
    super.init()
}
```

**New error:** `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff5f300ff8)` in this line of code: `self.init()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your this line :

```
let originView:UIView!
```

to

```
var originView:UIView!
```

And you are done.

Answer (score 2):

Try to modify this part.

```
 override init() {

      super.init()

  }
```

To

```
  override init() {

      self.init(UIView(), nil) // Or other initial values 

  }
```

If this is not resolve your bug, this is better way because init() call your custom init and initialize your variables.

**Edit on update**

Your modification is not correct

```
  override convenience init() {

      self.init() // This init referred "override convenience init()" !! So recursive call

  }
```

You must to give parameters of init call like i said before in order to redirect "override convenience init()" to "init(sourceView:UIView, menuItems:Array)".

Comment: For "nil" in second parameter you need to change the prototype of your init with "init(sourceView:UIView, menuItems:Array<String>!)"

Answer (score 0):

Interchange the 2 lines in the `init(sourceView: UIView, menuItems:Array<String>)`:

```
init(sourceView:UIView, menuItems:Array<String>){
      originView = sourceView
      super.init()
  }
```

Hopefully, this will work.

**Edit: Call super.init() in your first function**

Comment: I didn't get an error in the editor but if I run the app, I get an crash. I updated my question with the error message, crashing line ... . Hope you can help me.

Comment: If I replace `self.init()` with `super.init()` in `override convenience init()`, I get the following error: `Convenience initializer for 'SideBar' must delegate (with 'self.init') rather than changing to a superclass initializer (with 'super.init')`.

Comment: Remove the keyword convenience.

Comment: I removed `convenience`.  Now I get the following error: `Property 'self.orignView' not initialized at super.init call`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize all non optional mutable properties and all immutable properties (regardless of whether optional or not) before invoking the superclass initializer:

```
init(sourceView:UIView, menuItems:Array<String>){
    originView = sourceView
    super.init(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)
}
```

Note that since the `originView` property is immutable, you really don't need to make it an implicit unwrapped optional. The `sourceView` parameter passed to the initializer is not optional, so you can make that property a non optional:

```
let originView: UIView
```